# How to configure llvm's header files. Just like iostream、Windows.h

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

First time using llvm. now I have some tricky problems. I don't know what step is missing that prevents cpp from using llvm's headers.

---

**For example:**

```cpp
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
```

**Output:** Unable to open source file "llvm/IR/Module.h"

---

**Actual Status:**
[image: actual status]

---

How do I configure these headers to work properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get include / link flags and paths from installed LLVM via `llvm-config` tool. See https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html for more information.

In your case you'd need to check what is returned by `llvm-config` and injected into your `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables.

And certainly, your IDE must know about these flags / paths as well.

Comment: Hi brother. I remember replying to you two days ago. But it seems that I didn't reply correctly due to network problem. I built ``llvm`` and generated ``llvm-config`` but still got the error.